# Dynamic angular 2 expressions bind to view

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot, aot

I am fetching part of the page from some service. How can I achieve that angular expression or router staff working as dynamic content?

Controller.ts

```
 variable = 'some text';
 dynamicContent ='
     {{variable}} 
     Or
     <a  [routerLink]="contact"]></a>';
```

View.html

```
<div>
     {{dynamicContent}}//plain text 
     <div [innerHtml]="dynamicContent"></div> //html without angular expressions
</div>
```

So innerHtml is close. It can build html but cannot understand angular 2 expressions. I found out ng-dynamic module but it also undesrstand only html. The best solution atm is html outlet that i found on some stack questions. But it is not supporting AOT...

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Angular never processes dynamic content, except stripping some security relevant stuff if not sanitizized. Angular bindings and components are **only** processed when added to a components template statically.

You can create a component dynamically where you put the dynamic content into them components template

See also [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960)

Comment: it seems that it can be solution. Only question is how it is supporting AOT. I ll check it out

Comment: I don't know. The last thing I heard was that it doesn't work with AoT when the browser-dynamic platform is imported which is required here.

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:

```
dynamicContent = this.variable + ' Or <a href="#/contact"></a>';
```

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EqJRUs3mGKwjnXzbuwAo?p=preview

Comment: in your plunker you are using pure html <a href="#">Go to Site</a> which is working fine like I said. Problem is when I am trying to have angular 2 way links: <a [routerLink]='/page2'></a>

Comment: still pure html in variable: dynamicContent =  '<a href="#/crisis-center">' + this.variable + ' CrisisCenter</a>'; In my case I am using html 5 push state. My links not using # notation. This was like workaround a littlebit. 
dynamic content need to be placed in angular notation like:
<a [routerLinkActive]="'is-selected'"><a [routerLink]="['./Contact']"></a>